# Montgomery Multiplication in FPGA explanation

Tags: rsa, montgomery-multiplication

I'm trying to implement an RSA module in a FPGA. I choose to use Montgomery multiplication. I've found a document where the Montgomery Multiplication is pretty clear. I don't understand only a step.

The algorithm is…

$S[0] = 0\\  
for\ i\ to\ (k-1)\ loop\\
\ \ \ \ q_{i} = ( S[i]_0 + A_{i} \times{B_{0}} ) \bmod{2}\\
\ \ \ \ S[i+1] = (S[i] + A_{i} \times{B} + q_{i} \times{n} ) \div{2}\\
end\ loop$

… where $w$ is word length, $A$ and $B$ are the factors, and $S$ is the result.

If $q_{i}$ is only one bit (as far I understood), why does it use the operator “$\bmod{2}$”? What am I missing?

Comment: Perhaps a link to the _document where the Montgomery Multiplication is pretty clear_ would help. Edit the question, select that fragment, Ctrl-L, paste link will do the trick. $\;$ As to the question: $x\bmod 2$ is the low-order bit of the binary representation of $x$; while $x\div 2$ is $x$ with that bit removed (in the context).

Comment: There is no $w$ in the given algorithm. There is an unspecified $n$ though.

Comment: @fgrieu I know that $x \bmod 2$ is the low-order bit of the binary rappresentation, but when $x$ is only 1 bit there is no sense. The link of the document is : 
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1291939&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D1291939

Comment: @user13741 Sorry, I was hurry. There isn't $w$. 



$k$ is the word length and $n$ is the modulus of the Montgomery multiplication.